# How to write superscript Registered ® and Rx in Magento 2 Product name

Tags: magento2, product, product-attribute, custom-product-type

I have many products in the website having product name like "Cialis ® (Tadalafil) Rx 20 mg"
I want to write in superscript both "®" and "Rx" but they are not written in  tag because Magento Product name also show tag in frontend.
So what I have to do, help me out from this problem.

How to show ® and Rx both in superscript

Answer (score 0):

Use superscript tag

```
<sup>Rx</sup>
```